# List box sending data to textarea upon click of send button

Tags: php, javascript, forms, listbox

I am using a micro message PHP script that allows user to submit messages in a simple and clean form. It uses a database for the entries. The form part of it looks like this:

```
<form name="new_post" method="post" action="admin.php?page=wp-admin-microblog/wp-admin-microblog.php" id="new_post_form">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="postdiv" class="postarea" style="display:block;">
                    <textarea name="wpam_nm_text" id="wpam_nm_text" style="width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>
                </div>
                <p style="text-align:right; float:right;"><input name="send" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Send', 'wp_admin_blog'); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to add a drop-down list to the form and depending on what the user selects in the drop-down list, a custom text should be added to the beginning of the textarea (wpam_nm_text) message when the user clicks the send button.

Let me explain this. I want to add something like this:

```
<select>
 <option>Milk</option>
 <option>Coffee</option>
 <option>Tea</option>
</select>
```

...to the form, and if the user selects the option "Coffee", then I want to add the text "Coffee keeps me awake" to the textarea when the user clicks on the send button. So when the form is sent to the database, it will contain "Coffee keeps me awake" followed by what the user wrote in the textarea.

I would presume that this is possible using Javascript or PHP, both of which I have no good knowledge of, so detailed replies are beneficial. Also, if you require more info or script, by all means, feel free to ask.

Here is a fiddle if you want one: http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer posted by codingbiz will work for you ..(can't upvote,no priveleges :( ).

However if you want a javascript solution I think this should work for you ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setText(){

  var drink = document.getElementById('drink');
   var feed = document.getElementById('feed');
    feed.value = drink.value + " keeps me awake:" + feed.value;

    }

</script>

<form name="new_post" method="post"  id="new_post_form">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <div id="postdiv" class="postarea" style="display:block;">
                        <textarea name="wpam_nm_text" id="feed" style="width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                     <select id = "drink">
                         <option>Milk</option>
                         <option>Coffee</option>
                         <option>Tea</option>
                    </select>
                    <p style="text-align:right; float:right;"><input name="send" type="submit" onClick="setText()" class="button-primary" id ="submit" value='go' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
 </form>​
```

Comment: Very interesting, can you please elaborate exactly how your script works? I do not understand how to set a different value for each option.

Comment: Didn't get you completely.. do you want to have different text to be appended for each option .. e.g Milk is good ..and... Coffee is cool? something like that?

Comment: Sorry let me explain, if the user chooses Milk, then I want "Milk is white" to be pasted in the textarea, if the user chooses Coffee, I want "Coffee is brown" and so on. So different for each option. Currently, your code paste " keeps me awake:" no matter any option the user selects.

Comment: Created a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/13/
I have removed the form tag for now. Option now has text as well as value.. I think this does what you want.

Comment: Excellent, the only thing that I need to change is that I do not want the name of the choice in the results. So if the user selects Coffee, I want it to result "Tastes great:" if you can update the fiddle with this, I will then accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: codeheart i love you, this works :) The updated fiddle works fine. Funny enouch, I was using robbieAreBest's solution up until today when I got reports that my form does not function in Safari. So I tried your code and it works fine! I have accepted this as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can access your select dropdown value from the server side and append it to the text

HTML

```
<select name="choice">
 <option>Milk</option>
 <option>Coffee</option>
 <option>Tea</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$wpam_nm_text = $_POST['wpam_nm_text'];
$choice = $_POST['choice'];

$customText = "default";

if($choice == "Coffee")
   $customText = "Coffee keeps me awake";
else if($choice == "Milk")
   $customText = "WhatStuffYouWantHere";

//combine the dropdown value and the textarea value
$requiredVal = $customText.' '.$wpam_nm_text;

print($requiredVal);

//do whatever you want with $requiredVal
?>
```

That should do it

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail and how I use it. As I noted above, my knowledge of PHP is very limited. Ideally, if you could add the "Coffee" example that I gave in your code and I can understand it better. I will then be able to test it in my page and mark this answer as correct if it works.

Comment: include your dropdown in your form, give it a name, then in the page specified in your `action=xxxx.php` process the information like in the answer. The value of your dropdown and textarea are sent to the server which you can join together anyway you like just like in my answer

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I add the code that you provided to my action php file, then in the form, I add a dropdown list and name it what exactly? What value in your example goes to what? Talk to me as if I'm 5 year old and trying to understand this and it will work ;)

Comment: And what do you mean with **do whatever you want with $requiredVal**?

Comment: the value in `$_POST` are the name you specified for each control in the form. If you have `<select name="xxx">` then you'll `$choice = $_POST['xxx']`

Comment: If you want to use the value like inserting it into database, displaying it on a page, sending it as an email

Comment: Alright, I have updated the fiddle if you could have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/10/ I named the list "drinkSelection". Where do I insert that value in your code?

Comment: Okay, I just saw your update, allow me 2 minutes to test this in my site and I will update you, cheers brother.

Comment: I added the list as you wrote it and added the php code directly in the action php. I used the one that you just updated. It did not work. It did print the code at the top of the page but the text did not go through in the form. Do you know why and how to solve this?

Comment: Yes I did, lets continue in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15145/discussion-between-henrik-petterson-and-codingbiz

Comment: I could not make this work, not because the code is faulty, simply because I am having issues reading the code in my own page. Nonetheless, I have upvoted this answer for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, a simple bit of javascript can help you accomplish this.

```
<script>
    var drinks = {
        Milk: "does a body good",
        Coffee: "keeps me up",
        Tea: "is yummy"
    }; 

    function optionChange(){
        var drinkText = drinks [document.getElementById('drinkSelection').value]
        document.getElementById('wpam_nm_text').value = drinkText;       
    }
</script>
```

here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/6/

EDIT:
I did not see at first that this was on submission of the page.  For that, what codingbiz posted should work just fine.  This way should only be used if they can update the custom text.

If you did need to do it on the front end though, you could do something like this.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/14/

```
var drinks = {
    Milk: "does a body good",
    Coffee: "keeps me up",
    Tea: "is yummy"
}; 

function submitForm(){
    drinkText = drinks [document.getElementById('drinkSelection').value]
    document.getElementById('wpam_nm_text').value = drinkText + ' ' +document.getElementById('wpam_nm_text').value;
    document.getElementById('new_post_form').submit();       
}
```

```
                <div id="postdiv" class="postarea" style="display:block;">
                    <textarea name="wpam_nm_text" id="wpam_nm_text" style="width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>
                </div>
                 <select id="drinkSelection">
                     <option>Milk</option>
                     <option>Coffee</option>
                     <option>Tea</option>
                </select>
                <p style="text-align:right; float:right;"><input name="send" type="button" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Send', 'wp_admin_blog'); ?>" onclick="submitForm()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>​
```

Comment: That works, although I do not want the text to be added visually, only when the user clicks on the send button. So in other words, the user will not be able to see the "keeps me up" text. How is this possible? Can you kindly update your answer?

Comment: Just added an edit after re-reading your question.  Go with codingbiz's approach.

Comment: Thank you, however I am trying to understand codingbiz example, its rather difficult without a full script to look at.

Comment: One moment as I test this with my actual script!